Setting up secure DUAL boot w/ TPM2 and whole-disk (hardware) encryption for openSUSE and Windows 11
How do I set up whole disk (hardware) encryption (using the AES256 support built into the drive) w/ TPM2 for a dual-boot Linux/Windows11 laptop, as I have a need to have a good deal of shared data and documents between OSs (either NTFS or Btrfs) and duplication with use of Dropbox to sync requires internet access.
In my case, I am just talking about hardware encryption that is invisible to the OS (but somehow, presumably, the bootloader knows or it would not be a trusted boot).*  I realize it ins't prefect security, but its a lot better than what most people will have and good enough for my needs, right now.
I am setting up a new laptop (ThinkPad p14s gen5) and need to be able to support trusted boot into Win11 and/or openSUSE--both which support it out of the box, but w/o a shared encryption approach other than using whole-disk (hardware) encryption w/ the TPM2 chip stores the key. I mostly use openSUSE/KDE, (98% of the time, but Baldur's Gate 3 might change that if it doesn't run on WINE)
I don't think it is a huge inconvenience to type in a second password/swipe fingerprint/look at the camera so a single at-power-on authentication isn't a pressing issue for me.
In the past, I always have had a separate partition for ~/Documents and such that I sync w/ Dropbox using RClone and link to my home directory--and it replaces "My Documents" in Windows, if I need to dig out some other file from my Linux home, it is read-only and have not had problems w/ the WinBtrfs file system except that Win11 seems to freak out about it and I need to figure out how to self-sign the driver so I begin to have problem #1.
Problem #1:  How to use the hardware whole disk encryption w/ Trusted Boot, since trying to use Bitlocker and LUKS is just not going to happen.
Problem #2:  I cannot figure out in my UEFI menu how to export/back up whatever the key I use to encrypt it.  If my laptop dies and I need to pop the rather expensive Crucial T700 NVMe into a replacement, I would like to be able to do so even thought I love the quality time it seems to take to set up and customize a new OS install these days.
Problem #3:  Now, how do I get Windows 11 to boot w/ WinBtrfs (it likes to just remove the file system driver which is not a huge deal since I just reinstall it, but still not at all what I want my operating system to do.)  I.e. how do I sign the driver and tell Win11 to cool it?
I suspect there is also a way to use WSL2 to avoid even needing WinBtfs, if I can figure out how to mount a (potentially encrypted even) Linux partition w/ WSL2 and then access it w/ Windows software, as I don't have any GUI Linux apps in WSL.  That might be a better option, but good to compare the approaches as what works for me may not work for someone else.
It's mostly keeping everything safe if my laptop is stolen/lost.  I try to keep it turned off/locked up when not with me (but don't always, e.g. at a workgroup meeting, and we get a coffee break I don't want to reboot), and carry a security cable that has been connected to furniture/a big dog/my shoulder bag/belt on long flights to make sure it doesn't wander away when I am napping.
I should add an exFat partition w/ Veracrypt if I need a vault of sorts (e.g. private keys, those pictures I really should not have kept, etc. I am pretty sure I have seen it in an openSUSE repo, someplace)
Bonus Question: Would it be worth having a rescue OS (either a pre-canned one, or I can add some things to openSUSE and boot into, e.g. openSUSE MicroOS, as a third OS entry in Grub2) with a partition for REAR (or even just a copy of my /opt).  Besides screwing up my KDE repos and ending up w/ incompatible libraries for Plymouth--which is easy enough to fix in rescue mode once you get networking up, the biggest problem I have had was when my Btrfs got screwed up and I didn't have a bootable rescue so I could unmount, backup, fsck, etc. Or should I just keep a spare USB thumb drive handy so I can download burn a current install/rescue disk?
My other questions will be post to the database list, as it deals with using a data partition for PostgreSQL (and a bunch of graph databases).  It has worked in the past w/ MariaDB using AriaDB tables w/ the WinBtrfs driver.  PostgreSQL seems a bit more particular about security, but I have not installed the Windows version (I will probably use WSL2 which will likely avoid the whole problem with all of them--which is a bit easier, I think, than when I have used VirtualBox to run openSUSE in Windows to run other services) it seems. I don't have any sensitive data in the database, so I am not terribly worried, and if I do end up putting in some I will just encrypt it in the database.

One of the prior responses to this question is just wrong (Encrypting whole hard disk while dual booting Windows and Linux?) because so many SSDs support AES encryption, and there are software like TrueCrypt you can use (but I understand there are problems w/ the current version's performance w/ Btrfs and the old version, is well, old.  The other question I found was specific to the Win7 version of TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt.).

Unable to turn on secure boot doesn't talk about encryption.  Per Dual Booting openSUSE Tumbleweed with Windows 11 and Secure Boot I did grab a copy of the certificate.
There must be others, but I didn't see them!

Those responses are not wrong to that question; they are actually correct since most hardware encryption supported by drives ends up using BitLocker to accomplish the encryption.
